# Добавление данных в List

Tags: c#

```
PointPairList one = new PointPairList();

one.Add(0, 0);
one.Add(0, 0);
one.Add(0, 0);
one.Add(0, 0);
one.Add(0, 0);

List<PointPairList> two = new List<PointPairList>();

for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(i+" "+az[i]+" "+bz[i]+"");
    if ((i % 3) == 0) { 
        one[0]=new PointPair(az[i], 2);

        one[1] = new PointPair(az[i], -2);
        one[2] = new PointPair(bz[i], 2);
        one[3] = new PointPair(bz[i], -2);
        one[4] = new PointPair(az[i], 2);
        two.Add(one);
    }
}
```

В two[0] добавляется one на первом шаге, далее в two[1] добавляется onе на втором шаге, но при этом в two[0] элемент one изменился и принял значение one на втором шаге. Как мне сделать так, что бы значения в two не менялись с каждым шагом?

Comment: сделайте тег "java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переместить создание one в тело цикла